# how to measure time of encryption using key 256-bit in MARS cypher?

Tags: java, encryption, key

I'm developing a system that calculate the encryption time of method using different keys. the time works fine using the keys 128 and 192. but not the key 256. the output of the time using key 256 it shows as key 128-bit. this is part of the source code for the key method, because i think in the source code of the key there is something that make the system doesn't take the key 256-bit, i tried downloading the jce files:

```
private static int[] expandKey(byte[] key){
            int n = key.length/4;
            int[] tmp = new int[40];
            int[] data = new int[n];

            for(int i =0;i<data.length;i++)
                    data[i] = 0;

            int off = 0;
            for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                    data[i] =       ((key[off++]&0xff))|
                                            ((key[off++]&0xff) << 8) |
                                            ((key[off++]&0xff) << 16) |
                                            ((key[off++]&0xff) << 24);
            }

            int[] T = new int[15];
            for(int i=0;i<T.length;i++){
                    if(i<data.length) T[i] = data[i];
                    else if(i == data.length) T[i] = n;
                    else T[i] = 0;
            }

            for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
                    for(int i=0;i<T.length;i++)
                            T[i] = T[i] ^ (rotl(T[Math.abs(i-7 %15)] ^     T[Math.abs(i-2 %15)],3) ^ (4*i+j));
                    for(int c=0;c<4;c++)
                            for(int i=0;i<T.length;i++)
                                    T[i] = T[i] + rotl(s_box[(int).   (T[Math.abs(i-1%15)] & 0x000001ff)],9);
                    for(int i = 0;i<=9;i++) tmp[10*j+i] = T[4*i%15];
            }

            int[] B = {0xa4a8d57b, 0x5b5d193b, 0xc8a8309b,     0x73f9a978};
            int j,w,m,r,p;
            for(int i = 5;i<=35;i++){
                    j = tmp[i] & 0x00000003;
            w = tmp[i] | 0x00000003;
                    m = generateMask(w);
                    r = tmp[i-1] & 0x0000001f;
                    p = rotl(B[j],r);
                    tmp[i] = w ^ (p & m);
            }

            return tmp;
    }

    private static int generateMask(int x){
            int m;

            m = (~x ^ (x>>>1)) & 0x7fffffff;
            m &= (m >> 1) & (m >> 2);
            m &= (m >> 3) & (m >> 6);

            if(m == 0)
                    return 0;

            m <<= 1; m |= (m << 1); m |= (m << 2); m |= (m << 4);

            m |= (m << 1) & ~x & 0x80000000;

            return m & 0xfffffffc;

    }
```

this is the code:

```
byte[] plain = plaintext.getText().getBytes();
    byte[] K = key.getText().getBytes();
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    byte[] encrypted = encrypt(plain, K);
    String a = bytesToHex(encrypted);
    encryptedtext.setText(a);
    long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;
    time.append(Integer.toString((int) elapsedTime) + " ms \n");
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Please rephrase your story and give some expected and actual results

Comment: To test these kind of things create two large loops; one for the JIT to warm up and one to calculate the actual results. To get the time per call, divide by the number of loops performed. Use the higher precision nano timer. And (the most tricky part) actually do something with the results within the loops such as XOR'ing them into a result array otherwise the compiler may cheat and simply skip the encryption routine it it's entirety. Note that you should print out "the result" at the end, otherwise the compiler may still outsmart you.

Comment: @Mark Jeronimus the time result was with key 128-bit 6ms. With key 192-bit was 9ms. With the key 256-bit 6ms the program was acting as key 128-bit was entered. I believe that there’s something with the source code that make the program don’t accept the key 256-bit

Comment: @Maarten Bodewes this is only part of the source code where expand key i wanted to show the whole code. But I couldn’t here. Anyways there is XOR, padding and S-Box in the main code. But I will try creating loop, but could you please give me more hints for it. Thank you